# Negative position with overflow auto make element hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when using negative position(Ex. top:-20px) in absolute div and add overflow auto to the parent div. The text goes to **hide in all browser**. I want to make it visible. In my application structure its not possible to remove **`overflow:auto;`**. Do yo have any idea, how to make it visible? Just copy this code you will get the better idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body{
    margin:50px;
}
.Relative{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    z-index:1;
}
.Abs{
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px;
    background-color:#99CCCC;
    z-index:99999999 !important;
}
.RemoveOverFlow{
    overflow:inherit;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Relative RemoveOverFlow">
    <div class="Abs">This is a test text in absolute div</div>
Remove <br />
overflow <br />
from the <br />
relative div
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="Relative">
    <div class="Abs">This is a test text in absolute div</div>
Add <br />
overflow:auto <br />
into  <br />
relative div    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `overflow: auto` to `overflow:visible` in `.Relative` class

Example Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Wpcnx/

Comment: Thanks.. but its not possible to remove the overflow:auto. can we do without removing it ?

Comment: define later another rule for .Relative class with overflow: visible: it will overrides the first rule

Answer (score 1):

Can you have the `div .Abs` outside the `div .Relative` if so this would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/9CqUC/1/